# Flutter: What is the difference between the apk/release directory and flutter-apk directory under build/app/outputs?

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk

When I run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` I get three apks twice: once under the directory build/app/outputs/**apk/release** and once under build/app/outputs/**flutter-apk**. What is the difference between these two directories?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are the same. Old version of flutter use `outputs/apk/release` directory but they changed it to `outputs/flutter-apk` recently. The old directory is kept for compatibility with other building tools.