# Why flutter make two separate build folders?

Tags: flutter, dart

there are two seperate folders for app builds,

```
build/app/output/apk/release
build/app/outputs/flutter-apk
```

Using the **flutter build apk --split-per-abi** command will create two target folders. But why? they are the same! So what's the meaning of creating two target folders?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910148/flutter-what-is-the-difference-between-the-apk-release-directory-and-flutter-ap

Comment: Thank you so much. Should I delete this thread?

Comment: It's Okay! Others coming to this question someday would get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910148/flutter-what-is-the-difference-between-the-apk-release-directory-and-flutter-ap)

They are the same.

The old version of flutter use `build/app/output/apk/release` directory.

But within the new update it to `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk`.

The old directory is kept for compatibility with other building tools.